# How to run or execute DAML scenario's from command prompt / Linux terminal and is there is way to generate Transaction log created by DAML scenario?

Tags: unit-testing, daml

I am able to see the execution result of DAML scenario test result over DAML SDK using visual studio code, but what I need to run the DAML scenario from Linux terminal - Do we have any CURL command, or DAML command to test  DAML scenario?

I have already tried `DAML test`.

Is there is any other way? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

`daml test` does not output the final ledger state in any way. Its intended use is regression testing with scenarios so it merely passes or fails.

If you want a "Transaction log", you need to run your scenario in Sandbox (e.g. `daml sandbox --scenario Your.Module:your_scenario path/to/package.dar`) and read the transaction stream using a command line tool like [grpCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl).